# Is there data on ozone depletion potential?

Tags: database

I have interset in ozone depletion potential, and I'm looking for dataset or a list showing each ODP and  each moleclue. DO you know if it exists such dataset in Web ?

I have tried to look for it in Web, however I have not found it yet.
This page is the only page I found
https://www.epa.gov/ozone-layer-protection/ozone-depleting-substances

I expect that some oofficial report on ozone depletion potential exists where a lot of ODPs are shown